# Is the use of “flashing about” correct in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, verb-usage

Is the use of “flashing about” correct in this sentence?

> He hanged the animal’s heads on the walls, **flashing about** the heads to his hunter friends in the luxurious parties he held.

Comment: We would say "He hung the animal heads on the walls."  'Hanged' is normally only used to refer to execution by hanging.  (Feel free to ignore this if he is actually using nooses to hang the heads.)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly more common and acceptable at some previous point in time--the language appears to be dated. It would not be written that way now. And the word "flashing" (as it is used in this context) is typically only used now for things that are suddenly shown or revealed, like a cop's badge or a coworker's baby pictures.

Comment: Thank you. Is there another verb with the same meaning of showing some thing in order to make other people jealous?

Comment: Hmm...
"showing off" the heads...
"parading" the heads in front of ... (if the heads were portable)
"boasting about" the heads...
I think "showing off" might work best.